# Why SelectMany() not flattens string[] to char[]

Tags: c#, linq

I was just trying to understand how linq works and trying different things to test `Count()`, `GroupBy()`,`SelectMany()`. i am stuck at a scenario and i can't understand why `SelectMany()` is not flatting the `string[]` to `char` type.

Here is the code:

```
string s = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".ToLower();
char[] arratchar = s.ToCharArray();
var data= arratchar.GroupBy(x=>x).Select(y=> new {Alphabet = y.Key,Count = y.Count()});
```

This perfectly returns the alphabets count from a string.

When i do like this, it returns count of **a**:

```
string s = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".ToLower();
var countofA = s.Count(x => x == 'a');
```

But now i am trying to test the `SelectMany()`, i know it flattens the Collection within a Collection, but it is not working in this case, here is the code i wrote:

```
string[] s = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".ToLower().Split(' ') ;

var res = s.Select(x => x == "quick"); // this works
var re1s = s.SelectMany(x => x == 'q'); // but this not even compiles
```

Comment: Look at the actual types and values... it should all become clear once you do.

Comment: @Ehsan you are very confused, mate. That's not the correct usage of `SelectMany`

Comment: Using `var` does  neither help us to understand what you're trying to do nor you to understand what the compiler tries to do.

Comment: it was mistakenly added wrong corrected @TimSchmelter

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I think you understand SelectMany - you have written: `know it flattens the Collection within a Collection`. So - SelectMany expects collection to gave collection as output. Is `x == 'q'` collection? No - it's simple bool.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad the same applies...even worse..you are comparing a string with a `char`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad and I agree with pwas...I think you do understand it, that's why I stressed that you are getting confused (burning out?)...give your brain a break, leave the computer and go for a walk...trust me it'll help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SelectMany` signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector
)
```

As you can see `SelectMany` ([reffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx)) expects `Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>>` as selector -  the return value of selector must be an `IEnumerable` implementation. In the first case, `Select` expect any value (`Func<TSource, TResult>`): `x == "quick"` evalutes **true** / **false**, so the result will be enumerable of `bool` (`IEnumerable<bool>`). Unfortunately, bool is not assignable to `IEnumerable` - that is why it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

`x == "quick"` is a Boolean expression, so when you call `s.Select(x => x == "quick")` it will return `IEnumerable<bool>`

For the same reason `s.SelectMany(x => x == "quick")` won't compile. Because it needs a function which returns `IEnumerable<Something>`. Obviously, bool doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` so it doesn't compile.

I beliebve you have some misconceptions about `SelectMany`. SelectMany is used to flat some data structure. It should return `IEnumerable<T>` and not a `Boolean`. Take a look at its signature.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector);
```

It takes `Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>>` meaning it takes a function which takes `TSource` as parameter and must return `IEnumerable<TResult>`.

Let's say you have `List<List<int>>` which has there lists, all of them contains 3 integers. If you want to flatten the `List<List<int>>` to a single `List<int>` which contains all the 9 integers, you'll use `SelectMany` .

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };
List<int> list3 = new List<int> { 7, 8, 9 };

List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>
{
    list1,
    list2,
    list3
};

List<int> flatList = lists.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
//flatList will contain numbers 1-9
```

Answer (score 0):

Following shows what you can do with **selectmany**. Lets say you have a sentence word list as a character array and you want to know what characters are used :

```
List<char[]> sentence = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    .ToLower().Split(' ').Select(o=>o.ToCharArray()).ToList();
List<char> characters = sentence.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Note how `List<char[]>` is flattened to `List<char>`.

Comment: "char[] is flattened to char." - I think it's not good sentence. `List<char[]>` is rather flattened to `List<char>` :)